# Problems with Cloth stimulation baking

Tags: baking, cloth-simulation

I have a 680 frames long animation, I started to bake my cloth object but after 32% point cache the baking stops, I repeated the bake several times with different qualities but it always stops on 32%(on blender 2.90)
How can i bake the stimulation to 680 frames?

Comment: Have you checked your bake cache frame range?  Usually it stops at 250 frames by default.  Enter the 'end' frame as 680.

Comment: I have done that

Comment: The stimulation now works, actually I found that the motion of the collider mesh was very complex at those set of frames which made it really slow it took around 3 hours to 35% from 32%